# Separate Questions to Improve Google Search Results?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, exact-duplicates

I posted this question - [Where Can I Find the "Tameable" Chocobos?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/49805/where-can-i-find-the-tameable-chocobos) - which I also answered myself as I had collected the information while playing the game. At the time, Google didn't have a consolidated listing like this.

To drive more traffic to Gaming.SE, would it be appropriate to create separate questions for *Where Can I Find Purple Chocobo?*, *Where Can I Find Green Chocobo?*, etc? I think it's more likely that someone would search for a specific type than a comprehensive listing.

Since the answers to those questions would of course be duplicates I would want to create the question stub and then flag it for immediate moderator attention to close as duplicate.

**The end result** would be that someone searching for an individual chocobo would find the all-in-one listing on this site.

Thoughts on this?

Comment: If you're worried about the Googlability, just edit the question/answer to improve it (if it's not yours, take care to preserve the sentiment as best as possible)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's no need. Your answer already contains the phrases "Purple Chocobo", "Green Chocobo", etc. -- the whole answer gets indexed by google, not just the title.

In general, we don't want to create questions for the sole purpose of closing them as duplicates. Duplicates should never be asked, if at all possible.